# What ClientConfiguration settings would be optimal for establishing Elasticsearch connectivity

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We see the following error happen quite often for a [ClientConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/ClientConfiguration.html) with the following settings. What should we do in order to stop this timeout error from happening

```
withConnectTimeout = 5 seconds
withSocketTimeout = 3 seconds

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:75) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:346) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.doExists(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:182) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.exists(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:252) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.lambda$existsById$9(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:216) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.execute(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:401) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.existsById(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:216) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.0-M2.jar:4.2.0-M2]

        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]

        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.0-M2.jar:2.5.0-M2]

        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.0-M2.jar:2.5.0-M2]
```

Comment: that seems to be a networking problem if the connection cannot be established in 5 seconds; you could increase that value